# How to evaluate checkbox.isChecked() on a CheckBox Array?

Tags: java, android, for-loop, checkbox

I'm trying to evaluate if a checkbox is checked on a checkbox array, if one of them is not checked I want to assing 3 to n, but it only assings 3 to n when all of them are checked, any ideas?, Thank You.

```
for (int i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++){
    if(!checkBoxes[i].isChecked()){
        n = 3;
    }
}
return n;
```

Comment: you could add a break; after n = 3, if I understood you correctly

Comment: You should include the part where you declare `n`. From the code snippet provided, `n` should become three as soon as an unticked checkbox is found and there is nothing about "all of them" being checked (except `n` not becoming 3 if they are all ticked).

Comment: in your if condition you can add item in new array and after for loop you check length of the new array if it's empty then assign n=3

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer worked but it was easier for me to set a counter that increases everytime a checkbox is unchecked, if the counter remains 0 then n = 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (int i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {  
 if(!checkBoxes[i].isChecked())  {
 n = 3;                                                               
 break;
 }                                                                  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count the number of checked boxes in your array and then check the value of `n`. This example returns `0` if all boxes are checked and `3` otherwise:

```
int n = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++){
    if(checkBoxes[i].isChecked()) {
        n++;
    }
}
return n == checkBoxes.length ? 0 : 3;
```

Note that if the code snippet you are showing is all there is to it, you can also just `return 3` whenever a checkbox was found that is not checked.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked:
I set a counter then everytime the checkBox is unchecked the counter increases, if the counter remains 0 then n = 3.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your code like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++){
if(!checkBoxes[i].isChecked()){
    n = 3;
    break;
    }
}
return n;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int n=0,checked=0;
for(int i=0;i<checkBoxes.length;i++){
    if(checkBoxes[i]isChecked()){
    checked++;
    }
n = checked<checkBoxes.length?3:0;
```